# Does VSTS or TFS build process support custom triggers for build?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I don't see any options to customize triggers withing Build Definition except for source control change. I expected to be able to have some sort of script which can be run periodically to verify if new content is posted on HTTP or something more customizable then just source control change. Is it in fact missing or I misunderstood how build is being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/overview) to trigger a build however you want from an external process.

The built-in triggers (on source control change or on a schedule) are the only way to do it natively.

Here's an example of using the REST API:

`POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0`

with the body:

```
{
  "definition": {
    "id": 25
  },
  "sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master",
  "parameters": "{\"system.debug\":\"true\",\"BuildConfiguration\":\"debug\",\"BuildPlatform\":\"x64\"}"
}
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately requires remote trigger and secondly will not work with inhouse TFS for majority of webhooks which exists externally.